# HttpServletResponseWrapper to capture the response for static resource in java web?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I want to measure the **"content-length"** of response in javaweb servlet filter.

So I created a class which extends **HttpServletResponseWrapper** and **override** the methods **"getOutputStream"** and **"getWriter"**.

It works well except for the response of static resource, like requesting the .jpg file.

---

I use Tomcat 8.5 for the research, and here is the code:

```
public class TestFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void destroy() {
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;      
    TestResponse tRes = new TestResponse((HttpServletResponse) res) ;

    System.out.println(request.getMethod() +"  "+ request.getRequestURI());     
    chain.doFilter(req, tRes);
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
}
}
```

---

```
public class TestResponse extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {


public TestResponse(HttpServletResponse response) {
    super(response);
}

@Override
public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("in getOutputStream...");
    return super.getOutputStream();
}

@Override
public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("in getWriter...");
    return super.getWriter();
}

@Override
public void setStatus(int sc) {
    System.out.println("in setStatus...");
    super.setStatus(sc);
}

@Override
public void setHeader(String name, String value) {
    System.out.println("in setHeader...");
    super.setHeader(name, value);
}

@Override
public void setContentType(String type) {
    System.out.println("in setContentType...");
    super.setContentType(type);
}
}
```

Here is the testing result:

```
GET  /testWeb/
in setContentType...
in getWriter...
GET  /testWeb/spider.jpg
in setStatus...
in setHeader...
```

---

So I wonder is it possible to use **HttpServletResponseWrapper** to **capture** the response for static resource?

If possible, then how?

Comment: The code of tomcat servlet "DefaultServlet" which works for static resource show that it will use "getOutputStream" to output the resource. So it's strange

Answer (score 1):

Using HttpServletResponseWrapper to capture the static resource is ok.
The problem is the cache.